# How to update values in component after post request from ngx-modal

Tags: angular

I have  Clints modal component which post data to backend and returns back new Clients

```
submitForm() {

const body = this.clients;

return this.http.post('api/clients', body).subscribe(data => {

});
```

}

I have another compnent named ClientsCompnent which has all clients details

```
ngOnInit() {

if (window.screen.width === 425) { // 425px portrait
  this.gbSearch = true;
}

this.http.get('/api/clients').subscribe(data => {
  this.clients = data;
});
}
```

So how do i updated the clients variable in clientsComponent with the data i get back from post method in clients modal component

Comment: There is plenty info out there on how to do this... [take a read](https://medium.com/dailyjs/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you well, you need to pass an event from the clients modal to the client component.

Okay i think there is more than one way to solve it:

1. If the modal component is child of the clients component, so you should use @output like below:

In the modal component:

```
 private @Output() updateClients = new EventEmitter();
 submitForm() {

   const body = this.clients;

   return this.http.post('api/clients', body).subscribe(data => {
      this.updateClients.emit(data);
   });
 }
```

And in the clients component html:

```
<clients-modal (updateClients)="onUpdateClients($event)"></clients-modal>
```

Clients component ts:

```
private getClients(){
  this.http.get('/api/clients').subscribe(data => {
     this.clients = data;
  });
}

private onUpdateClients(data:any){
    this.getClients();
}
```

2. If there is no parent child relationship, you should use the sharedService please read follow the link below:

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Answer (score 0):

wrap the get request inside a function and call it inside both `onInit` and `submit` function

```
submitForm() {

    const body = this.clients;

    return this.http.post('api/clients', body).subscribe(data => {
        // if success call this 
        this.getClient();
    });
}


ngOnInit() {

    if (window.screen.width === 425) { // 425px portrait
        this.gbSearch = true;
    }
    this.getClient();

}

getClient() {
    this.http.get('/api/clients').subscribe(data => {
        this.clients = data;
    });
}
```